# Virtual keyboard in Monaco editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am new to Monaco editor and I am trying to use a virtual keyboard and type through the virtual keyboard. Do you have any idea how can I do that?
This is what I am doing currently

```
        var position = editor.getPosition(); // Get current mouse position
        var text = editor.getValue(position);
        var splitedText=text.split("\n");
        var lineContent = splitedText[position.lineNumber-1]; // Get selected line content
        var textToInsert = character; // text to be inserted
        splitedText[position.lineNumber-1] = [lineContent.slice(0, position.column-1), textToInsert, lineContent.slice(position.column-1)].join(''); // Append the text exactly at the selected position (position.column -1)

        editor.setValue(splitedText.join("\n")); // Save the value back to the Editor
        editor.setPosition(position+1);
```

first character will be inserted properly but when i trigger next character it goes infront of the previous character. Is there any idea to fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the answer

```
       var line = editor.getPosition();
        var range = new monaco.Range(line.lineNumber, line.column, line.lineNumber, line.column);
        var id = { major: 1, minor: 1 };
        var text = character ;
        var op = {identifier: id, range: range, text: text, forceMoveMarkers: true};
        editor.executeEdits("my-source", [op]);
```